# Calling .Net web service from Android Device

Tags: java, android, web-services, wcf, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and Visual Studio (.NET MVC) to develop an application where an android device may store/retrieve/process (login /registration forms etc) data by calling methods in a .NET application.

I want to know the best way to achieve this.
Should I create a .NET Web service on my .NET side? (WCF)

This is my first time creating a web service layer so I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me an article on how to achieve this.  I found a nice one below:

http://hintdesk.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-api-service-from-android/

Thanks guys, just checking if I'm on the right track using web services for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use .NET, then I would go with Wcf/Web api, depends on what you need.

[The basics of building an HTTP service using ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Configure your Service to be restful, and pass the data using JSON so it would be easy to consume using libraries such as Retrofit or Volley.
You can then use a library like Gson to parse the response.

Another upside is that if you later want to consume the data from other platforms (iPhone or web/mobile web) it would be very easy.

Comment: Thanks, this post has pointed me in the right direction.  I have now create a Web API and installed Retrofit on Android Studio.  Are there any tutorials on how to get these 2 to interact?  I have tried searching but can't find one for both

Comment: You should think about it a bit differently, because when you setup your WebService restfull, the server side technology doesn't actually matter. You just need to do a Get/post and get a Json reply.
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Use KSOAP the link has a very simple example [LINK](http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100&aaid=122)